# No instance of type variable(s) T exist so that ID conforms to Comparable<? super T>

Tags: java, generics

I'm learning about generics and I don't know how to resolve a problem.

This is the code:

```
public abstract class AbstractMapService<T, ID> {

    protected Map<ID, T> map = new HashMap<>();

    Set<T> findAll(){
        return new HashSet<>(map.values());
    }

    T findById(ID id) {
        return map.get(id);
    }

    T save(ID id, T object){
       map.put(id, object);
       return object;
    }

    void deleteById(ID id){
        map.remove(id);
    }

    void delete(T object){
        map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(object));
    }

    private Long getNextId() {
        return Collections.max(map.keySet()) + 1;
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
max(java.util.Collection<? extends T>) in Collections cannot be applied to (java.util.Set<ID>) 

reason: no instance of type variable(s) T exist so that ID conforms to Comparable<? super T>
```

Can someone explain to me why I get this error and how to resolve it? Thank you!

Comment: just a side note: you could change `entrySet()` by just `values()`, the code becomes a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means the elements in the parameter `Collection` of method `Collections.max` should implement interface [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). So it can use the `compareTo` to find the max elements in the `Collection`.

You can make it compile by declaring it this way:

```
public abstract class AbstractMapService<T, ID extends Comparable<ID>> 

private ID getNextId() {
    return Collections.max(map.keySet());
}
```

but I **do not** think this make much sense.

You might want to re-consider your design. With your current code, the `ID` can be any type. For exmaple, it could be `String`. And this time, your `getNextId` should not return `current maxID + 1`, since the `+1` is only make sense when your `ID` is a `Number`.

---

If `ID` is supposed to be `Long`, then you should not declare it as type parameter, you can write it this way:

```
public abstract class AbstractMapService<T> {

    protected Map<Long, T> map = new HashMap<>();

    Set<T> findAll(){
        return new HashSet<>(map.values());
    }

    T findById(Long aLong) {
        return map.get(aLong);
    }

    T save(Long aLong, T object){
       map.put(aLong, object);
       return object;
    }

    void deleteById(Long aLong){
        map.remove(aLong);
    }

    void delete(T object){
        map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(object));
    }

    private Long getNextId() {
        return Collections.max(map.keySet()) + 1L;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! The ID will be Long. But why it works only for ID extends Comparable<ID> or ID extends Long... why simply ID isn't enough?

Comment: @elvis Because `ID` is type parameter, the real type can be any type at run time. It could be a `String`, it could be a `Date`. `Collections.max` use `compareTo` method declared in `Comparable` internally. If `ID` does not has method `compareTo` at runtime, then java does not know how to compare these elements.